# Blob Fields in Crystal Reports using ASP.Net

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, crystal-reports

I tried various methods given online to insert an image in Crystal Reports dynamically from database but it did not work for me. The Image is still not getting displayed. I have tried doing it by using database expert, dataset and setting graphic location for a picture field but still no result. I have tried all methods possible I could find online.

I am using VS 2013 as my front end, SQL Server 2008 as back end and Crystal Reports version 13.

Thank you in advance

Comment: Where exactly would you have the images? (stored in database, stored in server with path stored in database, ...)

Comment: images are stored in image datatype on the database

Answer (score 0):

Since VS 2013 open your rpt file (not the cs code associated), over this, click with secondary button and select insert -> image -> browse in your computer image file. Later at moment to open the image you will paste in the rpt file (you will view first a rectangle with preliminar location of the image). In this way your image file will be converted to OLE Object inside rpt file (cristal reports file inside VS2013 Project).

Comment: thank you for your reply, but i need dynamic images from database